# Error POST request on Django Rest Framework (auth_user.username)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users, serialization

I try to create a new user (django user) via POST with

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UsuarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',
                  'password')
```

views.py:

```
class Registrar(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('usuarios', views.UsuarioViewSet)
router.register('tecnicos', views.TecnicoViewSet)
router.register('pedidos', views.PedidoViewSet)
router.register('mispedidos', views.PedidoMiUsuarioSet)
router.register('registrar', views.Registrar, base_name = 'registro')


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

When i make a post i get this error:
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

This works if i change the model User to Usuario...

Models.py:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    password = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

But i need to use the User model from django

Comment: Hold on, don't give access to password (even if these are hashed) through an API!!

Comment: The reason this fails, is because, like the error says, you already have a `User` with that `username`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The username field in the user model is required.**

This is why you must use this field in create operations.

Email address is not mandatory by default.

It happens on Django create user via a **unique** user username.